# unexpected AST node: . near line 1, column 63 [Update com.sathya.entity.Employee e set e.empSal=10000 where e.deptNumber]

Tags: java, hibernate

**This my DAO class**

```
package com.sathya.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.sathya.util.HibernateUtil;

public class EmpDaoImpl implements IEmpDao 
{
    private SessionFactory factory;
    public EmpDaoImpl()
    {
        factory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    }

    public List findEmpsByDeptNum(int deptNumber) 
    {
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        Query q=session.createQuery("from Employee e where deptNumber=?");
        q.setParameter(0, deptNumber);
        List list=q.list();
        session.close();
        return list;
    }


    public int updateEmpsByDeptNum(int deptNumber) 
    {
        Session s=factory.openSession();
        Query qr=s.createQuery("Update Employee e set e.empSal=10000 where e.deptNumber");
        qr.setParameter(0, deptNumber);
        Transaction tx=s.beginTransaction();
        int i=qr.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
        s.close();
        return i;
    }
}
```

**This is my test class**

```
package com.sathya.test;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.sathya.dao.EmpDaoFactory;
import com.sathya.dao.IEmpDao;
import com.sathya.entity.Employee;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        IEmpDao dao=EmpDaoFactory.getInstance();
        List list=dao.findEmpsByDeptNum(20);
        Iterator it=list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Employee e=(Employee)it.next();
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        int i=dao.updateEmpsByDeptNum(30);
        System.out.println("No.of rows updated:"+i);
    }
}
```

**I'm getting error like bellow**

> WARN: [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1,
>   column 52 in HQL: [from com.sathya.entity.Employee e where
>   deptNumber=?].  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use
>   named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.

Answer (score 1):

For the warning, change

```
  Query q=session.createQuery("from Employee e where deptNumber=?");
  q.setParameter(0, deptNumber);
```

to

```
  Query q=session.createQuery("from Employee e where deptNumber=:num");
  q.setParameter("num", deptNumber);
```

---

> unexpected AST node: . near line 1, column 63 [Update
>   com.sathya.entity.Employee e set e.empSal=10000 where e.deptNumber]

As far as I know, hibernate update cannot use alias. Modify

```
  Query qr=s.createQuery("Update Employee e set e.empSal=10000 where e.deptNumber");
  qr.setParameter(0, deptNumber);
```

to

```
  Query qr=s.createQuery("Update Employee set empSal=10000 where deptNumber=:num");
  qr.setParameter("num", deptNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, use named parameters. Use this updated methods, Hope it will solve your problem.

```
public List findEmpsByDeptNum(int deptNumber) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    // Change the query and setParameter like this 
    Query q = session.createQuery("from Employee e where deptNumber = :deptNumber");
    q.setParameter("deptNumber", deptNumber);
    List list = q.list();
    session.close();
    return list;
}


public int updateEmpsByDeptNum(int deptNumber) {
    Session s = factory.openSession();
    // Change the query and setParameter like this
    Query qr = s.createQuery("Update Employee set empSal=10000 where deptNumber =: deptNumber");
    qr.setParameter("deptNumber", deptNumber);
    Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
    int i = qr.executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();
    s.close();
    return i;
}
```